# server is undefined in ember cli acceptance test

Tags: ember-cli-mirage

I am trying to set up an acceptance test for an ember application that is using ember-cli-mirage

The doc says that server is supposed to be a global if you are in an acceptance test, but that is not working for me.

You can see the test/code here https://github.com/chrisortman/ember-cms-frontend/blob/master/tests/acceptance/consent-document-test.js#L7

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it start working.

I had to qualify my usage of `server` with `window.server`

https://github.com/chrisortman/ember-cms-frontend/commit/548189a18e472402def2b69881219e7c2519e0e5

**EDIT**

It works when I run the tests in browser with the /tests url, but not when using `ember test` or `ember test --server`

**EDIT2**

Seems due to a bug, but if you specify something for your host values it works

https://github.com/chrisortman/ember-cms-frontend/commit/745e28c3feafeee8b5f7f0faa7a554b0a364fd52